# Patient ou patiente (malade)?

Tags: genre

For a female patient (sick person), do we say "patient" ou "patiente"?

Quand on a un patient (malade) qui est une femme, on dit "patient" ou "patiente"?

Comment: I don't really know why you were afraid of an irregularity here... the term is indeed gender-marked : **une patiente**.

Comment: Google can't be of any help, but dictionaries, [monolingual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patiente#Noun) and [bilingual](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/patiente) are here to help. Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question.

Comment: Well a funny thing si that google does help with translations (in his case at least). For the femal version of a noun you can write **female** `word` **french translation**. [See here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=female+patient+french+translation)

Comment: I guess I didn't search the right way, then. Thanks to all. :)

Comment: @Robijoe What I meant is that Google translation should not be trusted - even if it can sometimes give a correct translation. I would never advise someone with a poor grasp of the language to trust a google translation, there are much better tools.

Comment: @Laure Yeah I understood that. I just wanted to give a simple tip for future simple researchs. Tho I would never recommend translating a full sentence as google seems to favorite using commonly used terms for ambiguous meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

patiente.

Example for male: Ce patient est malade.

Example for female: Cette patiente est malade.

Most of the time, words that change nature due to the sex, if it a female it will end up with "e".

Answer (score 2):

- «Cancer du sein: guide pour les patientes...» (Breast cancer: a guide for patients)
- «Le patient a des droits...» (patients have rights)